# Launch original Activity if phone is verified, otherwise launch verification Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to create a Auth scheme of sorts where if the user's phone is verified, I can launch the original intent, otherwise it launches the phone verification activity.

I also want to store the original intent and launch the particular activity after the user's phone is verified. I want to do this for multiple activities so an `if/else` would mean code duplication.

Is it possible? Like a login screen after a 401 return.

Thanks

Comment: I would start with an `if/else` statement to decide which activity to start.

Comment: that would make a lot of if/else statements, that part is clear. I was asking if there is a mechanism where I can specify that prior to launching, I check whether this activity requires phone verification - if so, launch the phone verification activity saving the original intent.

Comment: Then you need to edit your post and be more clear. As it stands, it sounds like you want to only ever start one of two activities which would require a single `if/else`

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, is my question clearer now?

Comment: Use a local file that stores a valid session id just like what happens when you log into a site on your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a base class that checks if user is logged on when activity is resumed:

```
public class SecureActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static Context applicationContext;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SecureActivity.applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
}


public static boolean isAuthenticated() {

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();      
    AppSettings settings = new AppSettings(SecureActivity.applicationContext);

    // Check if user not logged on or expired
    if ((settings.getLogin() == null) || (now > settings.getLastLogin() + Util.EXPIRATION_TIME_SECONDS * 1000)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isAuthenticated() == false) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class));
    }       
}
```

}

When user needs to login, it will start LoginActivity.

Now, you just have to create your activities and extend from this SecureActivity and they will be secured, like that:

```
public class MyActivity extends SecureActivity {
}
```

Comment: nice! never thought of that. Thanks